# Recreate Flutter's ios and android folder with Swift and Kotlin

Tags: dart, flutter

Hi I just found out that it is possible to create Flutter project with Swift and Kotlin. However, I'm already invested in my current projects and want to recreate the `ios` and `android` as Swift and Kotlin (currently they are default to Java and ObjC).

Thanks.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

use `-i` and `-a` to create new project, like this:

```
flutter create -i swift -a kotlin project_name
```

see also:https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels#example-project
[image]
then replace with `lib` folder from old project.

---

**update 2020.01.13**
swift and kotlin are default now. you can use those command to update exist project:

```
cd project
flutter create .
```

this command will **update your project**. then you can merge you old code into new project, and remove old code.
**make sure you backup your project before run it, and you know what are you exactly doing**

Comment: You can just delete the `ios/` and/or `android/` folder in your project and have them recreated using the command you suggested and then re-apply manual changes (easy if you use version control)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I only want to recreate ios folder. please help with the command to use!

Comment: @John Ravi you can create a new project in other path, then copy ios folder replace old one.

Comment: I understand that new project should hold the same name as original project. Am I right? @dujianchi

Comment: @John Ravi    yes, better to hold the same name as original project, because package name(android)/bundle id(ios) has relate by native project. but not absolutely. and you can create project with package name/bundle id ,like this: flutter create --org aaa.bbb prj   ,then new project's package name/bundle id will be aaa.bbb.prj

Comment: What is the command to create android version without kotlin support?

Comment: `flutter create -i swift -a kotlin .` within the project folder worked for me

Answer (score 38):

You can also run `flutter create -i swift .` inside your app folder, to regenerate ios folder.

I've not tested android, but I guess the same should work for it too - `flutter create -a kotlin .`

Comment: Is there a way to create a project without kotlin support?

Comment: @Igor Zboichik The given command does work for android as well, but you are required to add your project name after "create" to create or repair the given project.

Comment: @Janaka just switch kotlin for java in your command.

Comment: If your project folder name is not a valid name though, you can specify a new name like so: `flutter create -i swift -a kotlin . --project-name=my-project-name`. You should actually place the project name that is used in the `pubspec.yaml`.

Answer (score 11):

I just deleted default ios and android folder in my flutter project.
now in order to generate these default folder again you can use this below command :

```
flutter create .
```

Note : "." is also part of command , also make sure that your project folder name should not contain spaces or special  characters which are invalid for package name.

Answer (score 3):

## Generate iOS Folder

For Creating only iOS Folder into your existing Flutter project

`flutter create --platforms ios swift`

and output like this

```
Creating project swift...
  swift/ios/Runner.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata (created)
  swift/ios/Runner.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/IDEWorkspaceChecks.plist (created)
  swift/ios/Runner.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/WorkspaceSettings.xcsettings (created)
  swift/ios/Runner/Info.plist (created)
  swift/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/LaunchImage.imageset/LaunchImage@2x.png (created)
  swift/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/LaunchImage.imageset/LaunchImage@3x.png (created)
  swift/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/LaunchImage.imageset/README.md (created)
  swift/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/LaunchImage.imageset/Contents.json (created)
  swift/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/LaunchImage.imageset/LaunchImage.png (created)
  swift/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-76x76@2x.png (created)
  swift/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-29x29@1x.png (created)
  swift/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-40x40@1x.png (created)
  swift/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-20x20@1x.png (created)
  swift/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-1024x1024@1x.png (created)
  swift/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-83.5x83.5@2x.png (created)
  swift/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-20x20@3x.png (created)
  swift/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Contents.json (created)
  swift/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-20x20@2x.png (created)
  swift/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-29x29@3x.png (created)
  swift/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-40x40@2x.png (created)
  swift/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-60x60@3x.png (created)
  swift/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-60x60@2x.png (created)
  swift/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-76x76@1x.png (created)
  swift/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-40x40@3x.png (created)
  swift/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-29x29@2x.png (created)
  swift/ios/Runner/Base.lproj/LaunchScreen.storyboard (created)
  swift/ios/Runner/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard (created)
  swift/ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata (created)
  swift/ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/IDEWorkspaceChecks.plist (created)
  swift/ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/WorkspaceSettings.xcsettings (created)
  swift/ios/Runner.xcodeproj/xcshareddata/xcschemes/Runner.xcscheme (created)
  swift/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig (created)
  swift/ios/Flutter/Release.xcconfig (created)
  swift/ios/Flutter/AppFrameworkInfo.plist (created)
  swift/ios/.gitignore (created)
  swift/test/widget_test.dart (created)
  swift/swift.iml (created)
  swift/.gitignore (created)
  swift/.metadata (created)
  swift/pubspec.yaml (created)
  swift/README.md (created)
  swift/ios/Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h (created)
  swift/ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift (created)
  swift/ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj (created)
  swift/lib/main.dart (created)
  swift/.idea/runConfigurations/main_dart.xml (created)
  swift/.idea/libraries/Dart_SDK.xml (created)
  swift/.idea/libraries/KotlinJavaRuntime.xml (created)
  swift/.idea/modules.xml (created)
  swift/.idea/workspace.xml (created)
Running "flutter pub get" in swift...                               4.9s
Wrote 50 files.

All done!
In order to run your application, type:

  $ cd swift
  $ flutter run

Your application code is in swift/lib/main.dart.
```

Answer (score 0):

To recreate your iOS folder after u deleted it.

Run

```
flutter create .
```

Answer (score 0):

As at 2024, the command that works to recreate ios folder is

```
flutter create -i swift --platforms ios .
```