# Create android folder with flutter create

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

I want to delete existing android folder and recreate it.

Based on this post;
[Recreate Flutter's ios and android folder with Swift and Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53294148/recreate-flutters-ios-and-android-folder-with-swift-and-kotlin)

It can be done by

```
flutter create -a kotlin .
```

But I don't want kotlin support.

What is the command to re-create android folder **without** kotlin support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kotlin is the default on Android. Your other option is Java, if you want that use

```
flutter create -a java .
```