I delete runner folder by mistake and after i add it again the xcode not working and says no destinations
 I can not run application on any device or simulator in android studio or from xcode
i tried to select any destination but the destinations window are not opening
and i tried to making flutter clean and run application again and tried to restart xcode,
android studio and my mac and nothing changed

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77920994/18645340

Generate iOS Folder
For Creating only an iOS Folder into your existing Flutter project
flutter create --platforms ios swift

